# How to run Capybara tests using Selenium & Chrome in a Dockerised Rails environment on a Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, selenium, google-chrome, capybara

I feel like I am close, but have hit a wall and so would appreciate some advice.

My goal is to be able to run my system tests and (take screenshots) using Chrome.

The non-JS tests pass using `:rack_test`.

When driven by `:remote_browser` (my Chrome setup) I can visit a path, take a screenshot which displays **This site cannot be reached** 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Also worth mentioning is if I try to use vnc with `open vnc://localhost:5900` I get an error **Connection failed to “localhost”** Unable to communicate with “localhost”. Make sure the remote computer is available and the firewall is not blocking screen sharing.

I know I’m missing something but am stuck as to what.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file. I’m using the standalone Chrome image.

```
version: '3'

services:

  app: &app
    build: .
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp

  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/usr/src/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
      - .env/development/web
    environment:
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpack-dev-server

  web:
    <<: *backend
    entrypoint: ./bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
    command: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "5900:5900"

  webpack-dev-server:
    <<: *app
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:cached
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    ports:
      - "3035:3035"
    environment:
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

  database:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db_data:
  rails_cache:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  packs:
```

My `Gemfile` includes `capybara` and `selenium-webdriver`

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 3.32', '>= 3.32.1'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.142', '>= 3.142.7'
end
```

Then my `rails_helper.rb` file includes this

```rb
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
Capybara.server_port = 3000
Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"

Capybara.register_driver :remote_browser do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w(disable-gpu no-sandbox) }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :remote,
    url: "http://chrome:4444/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :remote_browser
```

When I run tests I start Docker with

```
docker-compose up chrome database
```

In my logs I see this about the Chrome service starting up.

```
chrome_1              | 2020-04-24 16:17:05,059 INFO spawned: 'xvfb' with pid 10
chrome_1              | 2020-04-24 16:17:05,060 INFO spawned: 'selenium-standalone' with pid 11
chrome_1              | 16:17:05.229 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
chrome_1              | 2020-04-24 16:17:05,230 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
chrome_1              | 2020-04-24 16:17:05,230 INFO success: selenium-standalone entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
chrome_1              | 16:17:05.289 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
chrome_1              | 2020-04-24 16:17:05.328:INFO::main: Logging initialized @260ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
chrome_1              | 16:17:05.486 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
chrome_1              | 16:17:05.548 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Then I run a system test with this

```
docker-compose run --rm web bundle exec rspec spec/system/example_spec.rb
```

My example test is very simple

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Example", type: :system do
  before do
    driven_by(:remote_browser)
  end

  it "should take a screenshot of root path" do
    visit root_path
    take_screenshot
  end
end
```

It runs and passes

```
[Screenshot]: /usr/src/app/tmp/screenshots/r_spec_example_598.png
.

Finished in 0.77216 seconds (files took 1.73 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Here is the log

```
chrome_1              | 16:29:55.662 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
chrome_1              |   "browserName": "chrome",
chrome_1              |   "chromeOptions": {
chrome_1              |     "args": [
chrome_1              |       "disable-gpu",
chrome_1              |       "no-sandbox"
chrome_1              |     ]
chrome_1              |   },
chrome_1              |   "cssSelectorsEnabled": true,
chrome_1              |   "javascriptEnabled": true,
chrome_1              |   "nativeEvents": false,
chrome_1              |   "rotatable": false,
chrome_1              |   "takesScreenshot": false,
chrome_1              |   "version": ""
chrome_1              | }
chrome_1              | 16:29:55.662 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
chrome_1              | Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}) on port 13909
chrome_1              | Only local connections are allowed.
chrome_1              | Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
chrome_1              | [1587745795.669][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
chrome_1              | 16:29:55.943 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: W3C
chrome_1              | 16:29:55.943 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session d8f42b8387f0160b95f333eac5c1b576 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
chrome_1              | 16:29:56.287 INFO [ActiveSessions$1.onStop] - Removing session d8f42b8387f0160b95f333eac5c1b576 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

And the screenshot looks like this...

[image]

Also, this is the error message when I try to open `vnc://localhost:5900`

[image]

It’s got to that point where I am close to admitting defeat and not testing these use cases so would really appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Comment: By setting `Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"` You're saying that the tests should be telling the browser to visit `http://localhost:3000` - but localhost on the browser is the browsers docker container which is not where your app is running.  You need to set it to whatever location the app under test is being run on from the chrome containers perspective.

Comment: Thank you, your help pointing me in the right direction to find a working solution (posted below). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Walpole for pointing me in the right direction.

I have it working now and thought I’d post the solution in case anyone else struggles to get the setup working.

**First point — vnc not working**

This is straightforward to fix—the version of Chrome I was using did not include this and it was necessary to use the debug selenium version.

The `selenium_chrome` service in `docker-compose.yml` becomes this

```
  selenium_chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
```

**Main networking issue**

This related to the `Capybara.app_host` as Thomas Walpole explained.

The solution took a number of steps. First, the test server now broadcasts on a different port, 4000.

The `web` service in `docker-compose.yml` has the port added.

```
  web:
    <<: *backend
    entrypoint: ./bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
    command: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "4000:4000"
```

The `rails_helper.rb` uses this port and `web` is the Docker internal network address for the `web` service.

```
    Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
    Capybara.server_port = 4000
    Capybara.app_host = "http://web:4000"
```

The final issue with my code was the location of this code. It also needed to be within the `Rspec.config` block.

**Complete `rails_helper.rb` code**

The complete working final relevant code in `rails_helper.rb` therefore was this.

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :headless_selenium_chrome_in_container do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless disable-gpu window-size=1440x768) }
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :remote,
    url: "http://selenium_chrome:4444/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_in_container do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :remote,
    url: "http://selenium_chrome:4444/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities: :chrome
  )
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...

  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
    Capybara.server_port = 4000
    Capybara.app_host = "http://web:4000"
    driven_by(:headless_selenium_chrome_in_container)
  end
end
```

Note: this gives the option to run Chrome headlessly, or with a browser accessible via `vnc://localhost:5900`.